# How to get name of resource in terraform provider

Tags: go, terraform

I try to get the name of a resource as configured in HCL but need the value in my custom provider's go code.

```
resource "example_server" "bob" {
  name = "server"
}
```

In the golang code I want to use `bob` as value for d.SetId()

```
func resourceExsampleServerCreate(d *schema.ResourceData, meta interface{}) error {
  // do some stuff 
  d.SetId("bob")
}
```

The plan is to replace hardcoded value of `bob` with a variable ;)

Comment: AFAIK you can't do this. The resource name is just for state management to give a concrete address to a resource. Do you have a concrete reason for why you'd want to do this? Normally you'd want some reasonably identifying thing such as the instance ID in AWS to be the resource ID, not whatever the Terraform code has as the resource name.

Comment: It is about an attachment resource that puts a user into a group. Create and Delete are easy, but update if one of both changes, or both. What to take as ID?

Comment: I am confused by the discrepancy between your code and your question. Your code certainly works (other than setting multiple resource IDs to the same value, which would probably cause issues), but is unrelated to a getter on the resource ID.

Comment: @MattSchuchard I am looking for a value for an ID. As teh resource's ID is already an ID I wanted to use it as an internal ID for the provider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of a resource as given in the declaration header is for Terraform's own tracking and is not available to the provider code.

One big reason for this is that the name in question is not useful on its own: it is only useful in the context of the full resource instance address, which in this case would be `example_server.bob` but in more practical configurations could be something more complicated like `example_server.bob[0]`, `module.foo.example_server.bob`, `module.foo["bar"].example_server.bob[15]`, etc.

If the remote object type represented by `example_server` requires a unique name *in the remote system*, then the way to model that is to declare an argument for the resource (conventionally called `name`, but you can call it whatever makes sense for the system in question) and have the user choose what to set it to:

```
resource "example_server" "bob" {
  name = "bob"
}
```

The user might decide to set the two names the same as I showed above, but in real-world configurations that is rarely appropriate because `name` often belongs to a broader namespace in the remote system than the resource name in the Terraform configuration, and thus the user will want to set it to a name containing some additional context in order to ensure the appropriate amount of uniqueness to avoid collisions between separate configurations and separate modules within the same configuration.

If you'd like to use the name argument value as the id then you can just copy it over:

```
  d.SetId(d.Get("name"))
```

That's a common choice for representing objects in systems that don't assign surrogate keys to each object, and instead use the object's unique name as the sole identifier.

Terraform correlates the data you return with the full resource address in the saved state snapshot after each apply, so as a provider developer you don't need to worry about the resource address at all: Terraform will provide you whatever data you returned from the last operation so that you can use it to plan the next operation.